# Views: how show a link to the translated entity?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, 9

I'm on D9. I've a View of *moderated content* nodes, so of *Content revisions* elements.

Those nodes are also translatable: the default language is *it* and the eventual translation is *en*.

The views formatter is a table which shows both original nodes and their eventual translations.

I need to show for the elements of default language *it*:

- a link to the translated language version if it exists - which could be not published yet, but just in "validation"
- or a link to the "add translation" form in case the translation doesn't exist yet

Is possible to do this in some way, with just configuration\modules?

Otherwise how should I proceed to realize it? Should I create a custom Views field or is there a better solution?